# Postgres join very slow because of temp table

Tags: postgresql

I have two simple queries that are effectively the same on a small-medium size table that are giving me radically different results and I'm trying to understand why.

This is the fast one (1sec):

```
select      *
from        financials.income f
where       f.itemtype in ('SALES') and f.company_id=6445
```

This is the slow one (1min):

```
create temp table t_co as select 6445 as company_id;
select      f.*
from        financials.income f
inner join  t_co on f.company_id=t_co.company_id
where       f.itemtype in ('SALES')
```

Here is the explain analyze for the fast one:

```
[
  {
    "Execution Time": 97.271,
    "Planning Time": 2.833,
    "Plan": {
      "Exact Heap Blocks": 29,
      "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
      "Actual Total Time": 96.876,
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 14822,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
          "Actual Total Time": 76.988,
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 14793,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plan Width": 0,
          "Total Cost": 69.98,
          "Actual Startup Time": 76.988,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Index Name": "unique_income_daterange",
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plan Rows": 956,
          "Index Cond": "((company_id = 6445) AND (itemtype = 'SALES'::text))",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 1883,
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Actual Loops": 1
        }
      ],
      "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
      "Relation Name": "income",
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plan Width": 75,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
      "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
      "Alias": "f",
      "Recheck Cond": "((company_id = 6445) AND (itemtype = 'SALES'::text))",
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Actual Startup Time": 96.406,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Startup Cost": 70.22,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plan Rows": 956,
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 1883,
      "Total Cost": 3698.02
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

And for the slow one:

```
[
  {
    "Execution Time": 69825.054,
    "Planning Time": 0.166,
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Hash Join",
      "Actual Total Time": 69823.936,
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 11135,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
          "Actual Total Time": 0.007,
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
          "Relation Name": "t_co",
          "Local Hit Blocks": 1,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plan Width": 4,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.005,
          "Alias": "t_co",
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Startup Cost": 0,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plan Rows": 2550,
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 1,
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Total Cost": 35.5
        },
        {
          "Node Type": "Hash",
          "Actual Total Time": 69787.311,
          "Peak Memory Usage": 3137,
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 11135,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Exact Heap Blocks": 25326,
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
              "Actual Total Time": 68990.682,
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 11135,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
                  "Actual Total Time": 52693.721,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 11135,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 193938,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Plan Width": 0,
                  "Total Cost": 107233,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 52693.721,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Index Name": "unique_income_daterange",
                  "Startup Cost": 0,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Plan Rows": 1565411,
                  "Index Cond": "(itemtype = 'SALES'::text)",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Actual Rows": 1519378,
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Actual Loops": 1
                }
              ],
              "Shared Read Blocks": 219264,
              "Relation Name": "income",
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "Plan Width": 75,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
              "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
              "Alias": "f",
              "Recheck Cond": "(itemtype = 'SALES'::text)",
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Actual Startup Time": 52699.492,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Startup Cost": 107624.35,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Plan Rows": 1565411,
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 1511066,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Total Cost": 317692.99
            }
          ],
          "Shared Read Blocks": 219264,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Original Hash Batches": 64,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 19128,
          "Plan Width": 75,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Original Hash Buckets": 65536,
          "Hash Batches": 64,
          "Actual Startup Time": 69787.311,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Hash Buckets": 65536,
          "Startup Cost": 317692.99,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plan Rows": 1565411,
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 1511066,
          "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
          "Total Cost": 317692.99
        }
      ],
      "Shared Read Blocks": 219264,
      "Join Type": "Inner",
      "Temp Written Blocks": 19192,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 1,
      "Plan Width": 75,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Actual Startup Time": 69793.165,
      "Hash Cond": "(t_co.company_id = f.company_id)",
      "Temp Read Blocks": 355,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Startup Cost": 357134.63,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plan Rows": 3019514,
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 1883,
      "Total Cost": 605158.39
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

There is an index on company_id, a primarykey on 4 columns, and a constraint to make sure that dates don't overlap. The slow query looks like its hitting a constraint that is used to make sure that dates don't overlap, but I don't understand why as I'm only joining on the one column?

```
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_income_daterange EXCLUDE USING gist (
validrangez WITH &&,
company_id WITH =,
balancedate WITH =,
itemtype WITH =);
```

Comment: Short solution: `create temp table t_co as select 6445 as company_id;` -->> `create temp view t_co as select 6445 as company_id;` (the temp table has no structure, no index, no statistics; the view has)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that you could put data into a view. I thought a view had to point at an existing table. 

Any ideas on why this is so much faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that for a temporary table no table statistics are collected automatically, so PostgreSQL plans the query without valid statistics and arrives at a bad plan.

You can fix that by running

```
ANALYZE t_co;
```

before you run the query.

The reason why the temporary view suggested by wildplasser works is that in this case the `SELECT 6445` becomes part of the SQL query, so that the optimizer has more information. Note that the temporary view does not point to *any* table.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like I should add this every time I create a temp table - unless there is a downside?

Comment: The only downside is that `ANALYZE` takes a while, depending on your `default_statistics_target` setting.

Comment: I also will say to increase temp_buffers, in my configuration it made all the difference.